# Compiling library in g++ using C++11

Tags: macos, c++11, gcc, makefile

I'm been attempting to compile an open-source C++ library (QuantLib-1.7) on my mac for several days but I seem to be encountering some kind of C++11 compatibility issue.

When I run `make && sudo make install` from the terminal the compilation seems to work except for a bunch of errors of the form

```
Making all in BermudanSwaption
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../ql  -I../.. -I../.. -I/opt/local/include  -g -O2 -MT BermudanSwaption.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/BermudanSwaption.Tpo -c -o BermudanSwaption.o BermudanSwaption.cpp
In file included from BermudanSwaption.cpp:22:
In file included from ../../ql/quantlib.hpp:43:
In file included from ../../ql/experimental/all.hpp:25:
In file included from ../../ql/experimental/volatility/all.hpp:21:
In file included from ../../ql/experimental/volatility/zabr.hpp:31:
In file included from ../../ql/math/statistics/incrementalstatistics.hpp:35:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp:14:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/accumulators/statistics_fwd.hpp:12:
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/print.hpp:50:19: warning: in-class initialization
  of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
const int m_x = 1 / (sizeof(T) - sizeof(T));
              ^
1 warning generated.
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with g++ not being correctly configured for C++11. I'm familiar with the fact that C++11 can be invoked by compiling with `g++ -std=c++11`. However, despite a lot of googling I can't find a way to modify the makefile such that `-std=c++11` is called when I run `make && sudo make install`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the section of the makefile which I believe is relevant:

```
BOOST_INCLUDE = -I/opt/local/include
BOOST_LIB = -L/opt/local/lib
BOOST_THREAD_LIB = 
BOOST_UNIT_TEST_DEFINE = -DQL_WORKING_BOOST_STREAMS
BOOST_UNIT_TEST_LIB = boost_unit_test_framework-mt
BOOST_UNIT_TEST_MAIN_CXXFLAGS = -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
CC = gcc
CCDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CFLAGS = -g -O2
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS =  -I/opt/local/include
CXX = g++
CXXCPP = g++ -E
CXXDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
```

Here is the output from running "g++ -v":

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Makefile.am: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5j7qohwfup81od/Makefile.am?dl=0

Makefile.in: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t92hft9ea2ar1zw/Makefile.in?dl=0

QuantLib-1.7 directory: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ulj0y68m8x35zg8/AAA-w7L2_YWIP8_KnwURErzYa?dl=0

Full error log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g09lcnma8skipv7/errors.txt?dl=0

Comment: Why not `brew install quantlib` ?

Comment: ok, giving that a shot now.

Comment: `g++ -I/opt/local/include/ -I/opt/local/include/boost BermudanSwaption.cpp \
>     -o bermudanswaption -L/opt/local/lib/ -lQuantLib` followed by `./bermudanswaption` seems to run successfully now. This all seems very confusing. Is there somewhere I can read about how quintib's header and cpp files are organized in the file system? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just edit the line that says "CXX = g++" to make it say "CXX = g++ -std=c++11"?

Answer (score 3):

Add something like

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

to your `Makefile`. This will work regardless of the Darwin-specific munging of the `g++` executable---it's really `clang++`.

References:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options
- https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html
- http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Comment: Hi rubicks. I actually tried adding `CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` to the extensionless makefile and this did not work. I tried adding the line to Makefile.am which leads to the following error: `cd . && /bin/sh /Users/james/Dropbox/Finance/QuantLib-1.7/config/missing automake-1.14 --foreign Makefile
/Users/james/Dropbox/Finance/QuantLib-1.7/config/missing: line 81: automake-1.14: command not found
WARNING: 'automake-1.14' is missing on your system.`

Comment: @user11881 okay, that changes everything. If you have autotools already working, editing any generated `Makefile` isn't recommended. Instead, try adding `AM_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` to your `Makefile.am`

Comment: @user11881 , also grab the latest stable autotools if you're missing them: `brew install autoconf automake libtool autoconf-archive`

Comment: ok, ran `brew install autoconf automake libtool autoconf-archive`, added `M_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` to `Makefile.am`, but I'm still getting `cd . && /bin/sh /Users/james/Dropbox/Finance/QuantLib-1.7/config/missing automake-1.14 --foreign Makefile
/Users/james/Dropbox/Finance/QuantLib-1.7/config/missing: line 81: automake-1.14: command not found
WARNING: 'automake-1.14' is missing on your system.`

Comment: `You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>`

Comment: By the way `perl --version`, `autoconf --version` and `m4 --version` all seem to work.

Comment: @user11881, let's take this discussion elsewhere. Here, for instance: https://github.com/rubicks/quantlib

Comment: hi rubicks, I just created a github account but can't seem to contact you. username is noo-space. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you already have, and are familiar with `homebrew`, my suggestion would be to use that to install and manage `quantlib` like this:

```
brew install quantlib
```

That will then build and put all the files in `/usr/local/Cellar/quantlib` under some version number that is not of importance. The important thing is the the tools are then linked into `/usr/local/bin` so all you need to do is make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH.

That gives you access to the tool `quantlib-config` which is always linked to the latest version and it knows which version that is. So, if you run:

```
quantlib-config --cflags
```

it will tell you what the correct path is for your `includes` like this:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/quantlib/1.6.1/include
```

Likewise, if you run:

```
quantlib-config --libs
```

it will tell you the correct linking directories and libraries for your latest version.

In short, all you need to do to compile is:

```
g++ $(quantlib-config --cflags --libs)
```

and it will always pull in the version you are using.

Note that if you use a Makefile, you will need to double the dollar signs.

Comment: Hi Mark. If I am not mistaken, your answer refers to compiling the example files using the pre-compiled quantlib binary package downloaded from brew.  I am actually more interested in compiling the quantlib library for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I eventually managed to compile the Quantlib library for future reference. It is probably not the most efficient/elegant method but it appears to work.

1. I followed the steps given in http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml and found that running `make && sudo make install` led to the error reported in the OP.
2. Create a new static library C++ project in Eclipse called 'Quantlib'
3. Copy the ql directory located in the .tar file to the Quantlib Eclipse workspace
4. Right-click Quantlib > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross G++ Compiler: Change the Language standard to ISO C++ 11 (-std=c++0x)
5. Right-click Quantlib > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols: Add the following include directories for GNU C++

   opt/local/include

   /Quantlib (check "Is a workspace directory")

   /opt/local/include/boost.
6. Build the Quantlib project (around 34 min on MacBook Air 1.8 GHz Intel Core i7)
7. Create a new C++ executable project (e.g. BermudanSwaption) and copy the BermudanSwaption.cpp into the BermudanSwaption Eclipse workspace
8. Repeat steps 4. and 5. for the BermudanSwaption Eclipse project
9. Right-click BermudanSwaption > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > References: check Quantlib (the Library Paths tab should now contain the entry '/Quantlib/Debug')
10. Build and run the BermudanSwaption executable project

---

QuantLib-1.7

OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools Version: 8.8.0.201509131935

Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b)

xcode-select version 2339.

Comment: Additional note: I found that it was important to choose the compiler as "Cross GCC" for the Quantlib static project. If I instead chose "MacOSX GCC" I found that the entire library would recompile each time I tried to compile an executable project (I chose "MacOSX GCC" for the executable projects)